# PHP MySQL Query from two different tables based on result from first query

Tags: php, mysql, database, web

I have a standard select query which selects all records from the `products` table and then display it in a table.
I need another query to run after that based on the result, in order to get the a field from the `customers` table.

So for example. my query from the `products` table shows the `user_id` field. I need to run a SQL query simultaneously in order to get the `user_name` from the `customers` table.

```
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM products (SELECT eu_name FROM customer WHERE $id_mobile = $id_mobile");

echo "<table border='1'>
<tr>
<th>user_id</th>
<th>user_name</th>
<th>selected_product</th>


while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC))

echo "<td>" . $row['eu_name'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['user_name'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['selected_product'] . "</td>";
```

Comment: you can do with join but before that u need to post the table structures in your question.

Comment: in your given example, you haven't closed the first `echo`.

Comment: You definitely do not need a second a query. You just need to improve the first one.

Comment: @Nikola Hi that was just a quick copy and paste, just so that people have an idea what im talking about.

Comment: @AbhikChakraborty - what exactly do you need from the table stucture

Comment: your database table structures `products` and `customers`

Comment: customers(user_id, user_name, user_email) products (product_id, product_name, user_id)

Comment: @Nikola is it not easier to just close the php tag and then reopen it when you get to the while statement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the given table structure

```
customers(user_id, user_name, user_email) 
products (product_id, product_name, user_id)
```

You can get all the products associated with customer as

```
select p.product_id,p.product_name,u.user_name,u.user_email
from products p
inner join customers u on u.user_id = p.user_id
```

You can add where condition for any additional filter of data.